# import error __init__.py how to fix this error

Tags: python, pycharm, importerror

I am kind of an amateur to Pycharm.
Been trying to work with the Turtle package. It is clearly installed in the Pycharm,
but every time I import and run it, I see the below error.
I have been searching the net and all I could see was to check the interpreter and mine is the latest Python (3.10).
It will be really helpful if someone can suggest a remedy to this, this is happening with all the packages in fact.
Thank you!

```py
from turtle import Turtle
ImportError: cannot import name 'Turtle' from 'turtle' (/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/turtle/__init__.py)
```

Comment: "this is happening with all the packages in fact"—please say more about this. Can you provide another example? If all of your imports are failing with similar errors, something may be wrong with your Python installation or at least the current environment.

Comment: could you try reinstalling the turtle package? and dont forget to choose the right interpreter

Comment: @PapopLekhapanyaporn, [`turtle` is part of the standard library](https://docs.python.org/library/turtle.html#module-turtle) (though it may ship as a separate OS-level package). But anyway, OP says "this is happening with all the packages in fact" so it's unlikely to be an issue with that module.

Comment: @Chris thankyou for the attention, I am really hopefull that the issue will finally get resolved! Its been bugging me for a few days now and hampering my learning process. I shall try my best to respond to your query. When I had installed prettytables, it was still giving me the same Import error.

Comment: I uninstalled and reinstalled the Turtle package still getting this error.       'File "/home/nishadingale/PycharmProjects/day 18 start/main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from turtle import Turtle
ImportError: cannot import name 'Turtle' from 'turtle' (/home/nishadingale/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/turtle/__init__.py) '

Comment: The error in your comment shows a different path than in your question: `/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/turtle/__init__.py` vs. `/home/nishadingale/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/turtle/__init__.py`. How did you install Python? Are you trying to use a virtual environment?

Comment: That would probably be different beacuse i removed and reinstalled the turtle package.
And I am using a fedora OS, and have installed PYcharm on that.
Also ended up idownloading a python version additionally, I am not sure if that is the problem??